# Laravel ,Column already exists :1060 Duplicate column name

Tags: php, laravel

### **I am running laravel version 5.4.22**

I use `php artisan migrate:rollback` in terminal then error message bellow

> H:\wamp_server\www\cms>php artisan migrate:rollback
>
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column
>   already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'is_admin' (SQL: alter
>   table `posts` add `is_admin` int not null)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060
>   Duplicate column name 'is_admin'

migration code below

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddIsAdminColumnToPostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('is_admin')->unsigned();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //

            $table->integer('is_admin');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are definitely looking at the wrong migration. Find the migration for the table `posts`. you should also try `composer dump`.

Comment: Has been fixed ,migration code. please solve my problem

Comment: well your trying to add the column in the down function as well, that's the error

Comment: please explore your solution. and sorry for my bad English

Comment: see my answer, it explains it all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your code is wrong, you are adding the column in the down function as well, see code below to fix:

```
public function down()
{
    //
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('is_admin');
    });
}
```

Laravel doc, showing this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#dropping-columns

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer . now, My problem is solved

Comment: this is not the best way, cause you lose your data in `is_admin` column.

Comment: that's kinda the point of rolling back @MoeinPorkamel what I have shown is directly from the laravel docs.

Comment: thanks man. it worked didn't notice that i did the same thing in the down method

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, Column already exists: Duplicate column name 'created_at'

I think it was due to

```
$table->timepstamps('dob');
```

my previous code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps('dob');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

when I remove 's' form timestamp, like

```
 $table->timestamp('dob');
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. So, I asked composer for help:))

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

And then:

```
composer update
```

//You can encounter this issue when you try to update existing columns into a database.

You can read more about this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#modifying-columns).

Comment: Composer has nothing to do with it.